# Rails runner without spring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have rails 4.2 + sidekiq on ubuntu setup and I'm starting my jobs with cron every hour with something like

```
bin/rails runner -e production 'MyJob.perform_later'
```

This basically take a job and puts data to redis, so that sidekiq could take it and start from there. But everytime i do this I have this spring proccesses stuck and waiting for something (consuming memory)

```
ps aux | grep spring
root      Sl   07:13   0:00 spring server | myapp | started 6 secs ago
root      Ssl  07:13   0:03 spring app    | myapp | started 6 secs ago | production mode
```

Sometimes I see like 10 of those. Is there any way not to start spring server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This happens because you are using the `spring` gem and your `bin` folder has been "springified".

If you take a look in the `bin/rails` file you will see that `spring` is loaded before moving on with running whatever you requested from it.

You could "un-springify" your bin folder by running

```
bin/spring binstub --remove --all
```

This would mean of course that you opt out from all performance benefits that spring provides you. This should be OK for production environments. In fact, it is recommended that you **do not install spring in your production environments** [1].

So I suggest that you modify your `Gemfile` and place `spring` under the `development` group. In production you usually do something like:

```
bundle install --without development test
```

That way spring will never make it to your production servers. See also [this related issue](https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/318) on Github.

--

1 . [Spring project readme file](https://github.com/rails/spring#deployment)

Answer (score 29):

If you want to keep spring in general, you can temporarily disable spring for a single command by prefixing it with the `DISABLE_SPRING` environment variable:

```
DISABLE_SPRING=1 bin/rails runner -e production 'MyJob.perform_later'
```